# Adding in Tasks time spend on them with option to add endlessly until is Task done

Tags: php, time, task, implementation, espocrm

I would like to add a feature to my EspoCRM tasks where I can track the time spent on them along with descriptions of what happened during that time. For example, on Monday, I worked on task for 8 hours and I'll add a description saying what I did, such as "worked on this, that, and the other". On Tuesday, I'll repeat the process, and so on until the end of the week, with the time spent on the project gradually accumulating and showing. Something similar to Jira software. Could someone help me and guide me? Thank you very much.

I tried to create a certain type of field for it, but EspoCRM doesn't offer an option (or I couldn't figure out how) to do time tracking. I assume it will have to be written in PHP in the code. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, your question will probably be closed unless you can add some code which is causing you problems and describe what you have tried to do to make it work. Requests for general help about an API are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please read the help section on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).